# Syntax to Conditionally Retrieve List Member

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working with some open-source C# code for a USB HID library that I'm trying to modify. My C# (and OOP in general) are VERY rusty, so forgive the basic question.

The premise is simple: check for enumerated HID devices, and if one of the devices matches my desired VID and PID, get and return the full path to the device. The first part (checking for a match) work fine, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax to then return the path to that same matching device.

```
 public static string IsConnected(string deviceVID, string devicePID)
 {
      if (EnumerateDevices().Any(x => x.VID == deviceVID && x.PID == devicePID))   
      {
          return EnumerateDevices().Select(x => x.Path).Where(x => x.Attributes.ProductId == devicePID); 
      }
      else
      {  
         return "False"; 
      }
 }
```

VS15 complains that "'string' does not contain a definition for 'Attributes' and no extension method 'Attributes' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found".

I get this, looks like Where accepts ints only. Is there something else in the .NET framework Enumerable class that would work like I'd like? Or an easier way to do this?

Comment: Try to change the order of `.Select()` and `.Where()` calls and add `.FirstOrDefault()`: `return EnumerateDevices().Where(...).Select(...).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: you need : ``return EnumerateDevices().Where(x => x.Attributes.ProductId == devicePID).Select(x => x.Path)`` but this will still not compile as your method return type is ``string`` not ``IEnumerable<string>``

Comment: read the linq chain from left to right.

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, as Alberto pointed out below, that was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you want first the paths (a string collection), with the `Select()`, and then filtering your collection, with the `Where()`, where you don't have any `Attributes` property.

Your LINQ query should apply first your filter and then select the path of the object you're looking for:

```
return EnumerateDevices().Where(x => x.Attributes.ProductId == devicePID).Select(x => x.Path).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: There's still a problem here: OP's function returns a `string` but this code returns a collection of strings

Comment: @JoshPart Thanks for the remark! I was just editing the query, it should be fine now!

Comment: @Alberto Solano Thanks. that did it!

Answer (score 0):

Based on this part of your question:

> if one of the devices matches my desired VID and PID, get and return
>   the full path to the device... but I can't seem to figure out the syntax to then return the path to ***that same matching device***.

You could change the method to something like this:

```
public static string IsConnected(string deviceVID, string devicePID)
{
   //This line will look for the desired device and return it. 
   //If there is no match device will be null.
   var device = EnumerateDevices()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.VID == deviceVID && x.PID == devicePID);

   return device != null ? device.Path : "False";
}
```